# CQ: Content centric OR page centric?

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem, wcm

I have a query regarding CQ. Your reply will really make the difference to my understanding.

In other CMS like Vignette, content authors create the contents separately (not directly on the page) for ex. products details and then those contents are iterated / processed to display on the page. But in CQ, the scenario is other way round. Authors directly create the content on the page. Now if same content is needed on other page, how will that be re-used ?

Regards,
Ronak

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing content between Adobe CQ5 pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787449/sharing-content-between-adobe-cq5-pages)

Comment: If I create page with FORM in it (for product text, product image, description etc), still it would need separate page for each product I guess to enter details via form !!?

Answer (score 0):

Content can be reused across pages via [Reference components](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/author/page-authoring/default-components/editmode.html#Reference).  From the docs:

> The Reference component lets you reference text in another part of a
>   CQ based website (within the current instance). The referenced
>   paragraph will then appear as if it was on the current page. Instead
>   of referencing a specific paragraph, the path can also be modified to
>   specify an entire [paragraph-system]...

There are some other techniques for sharing content and reference data across pages, including inheritance and "data components," described [in this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787449/sharing-content-between-adobe-cq5-pages?rq=1).